# Value of uint8_t after being converted from uint_16t

Tags: c, uint, uint8t, uint16

I have to do a small assignment for school. I am writing this in C. The question is:

Given

```
uint16_t A[] = { 0xabce, 0x43fe, 0xcf54, 0xffff };
uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)&A[0];
```

What is the value of `p[3]`?

I did some research and found that the numbers will be put back into my computer using little-endian. So

```
p[] = {171, 67, 207, 255}
```

However, when I print `p[]` I get

```
p[0] = 206
p[1] = 171
p[2] = 254
p[3] = 67
```

I am very confused by this, can anyone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: You are aware right that `p[0]` and `p[1]` will both point to separate bytes of A[0]?

Comment: Casting pointers does no conversion. `p[0]` is the first byte of `A[0]`, `p[1]` the second byte of `A[0]`, `p[2]` is the first bytes of `A[1]`, etc.

Comment: `uint8_t` is not a character type, therefore this is undefined behavior.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo thanks! I get it now

Comment: @Ben, thanks dude! I get it now, pretty simple actually :D

Comment: @EOF It may be a character type, and usually is

Comment: @M.M How can a `uint8_t` not be a character type?  Is that a type only concern as it certainly must have the same range and size of `unsigned char`?

Comment: @chux it could be an extended integer type , in theory

Comment: @M.M  Hmmm do you mean like `unsigned char` is `16-bit` and `uin8_t` is 8-bit? Does not `sizeof()` need to work, even for extended integer types? `sizeof(unsigned char)` must be 1.  and `uint8_t` has no padding.  So I can't see it working "in theory".  (No need to reply as this is getting far off OP's post.)

Comment: @chux that situation isn't possible - there cannot be any type smaller than `char`. Not sure what was unclear about my previous comment? `char` and `uint8_t` would both be 8-bit, however the first would be a character type and the second would be an unsigned integer type (actually a typedef for an unsigned integer type, since `uintN_t` must be a typedef)

Comment: "unsigned char" and "uint8_t" are one and the same data type as far as the computer is concerned. The later is created as a semantic help to remind the developer that those values should not be treated as text - 
One could, theoretically have a computer architecture and compiler where the char data type would be different from 8bit, but that would simply make most C programs fail - while a program using `uint8_t` would still work.

Comment: Also, it is 2016, and one should not assume each text character is always 1 byte (8 bit) wide. Programs behaving this way as plain, simply, incorrect. For dealing with text in C, one needs a higher level library, or system functions, that are aware of character encodings. For more information, read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @jsbueno The first sentence of your comment is not guaranteed by the C Standard although it is a common way that compilers implement uint8_t.  The situation of `char` not being 8-bit but `uint8_t` working is forbidden by the C Standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, jsut to be clear - in a little endian machinne, this declaration:

```
uint16_t A[] = { 0xabce, 0x43fe, 0xcf54, 0xffff };
```

Will but these bytes in order, in your memory:

```
ce | ab | fe | 43 | 54 | cf | ff | ff |
```

(In decimal):

```
206|171 |254 | 67 | 84 | 207| 255| 255|
```

So, when you tell the compiler that starting at the very same position in memory, you can read numbers that are one byte long, what is retrievable in your "p" vector are the 8 numbers above.

```
uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)&A[0];
```

(Which could also be written simply `uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)A;`)

Keep in mind that in C, it is the developer's task to know how long a vector is. In this example, it might be that one would have the convention that the number "0xffff" would end the 16bit sequence, for example. Either way, you have twice that number of elements to read as 8 bit.